# Appium is selecting the wrong locator

Tags: java, android, xpath, appium

I am testing a sample Android app on an Android 6.0 phone and running `Appium UI version 1.10.0` and `java version "1.8.0_111"`. I need to click on the Office Location menu item but I am unable to find a suitable locator.

Here are the snapshots from Appium Inspector.

[image: Appium Inspector 1]

I tried using the recording feature in Appium Inspector as well which does send me to the correct screen on the app.

[image: Appium Inspector 2]

However, when I use the following line of code in my project, the incorrect menu item is selected.

```
MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc=\"73: [Office Locations]\"])[2]");
el1.click();
```

I would expect the Office Locations menu item to be selected, instead, a different menu item with a different cont_desc is being selected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to find same xpath in appium inspector and check how many matching elements it is showing.

If it shows only one matching element then try to perform some action on found element and check where it is performing action.

Also try to use resource-id to find the element. If not present for this element then use its parent element or sibling elements.

Many a time people mistakenly get the xpath of element behind actual element and face this kind of problem. Try to avoid generated xpath.

Comment: Thank You. Your suggestion let me discover two matching xpaths for `//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="73: [Office Locations]"]`. The bottom right home button has the same content-desc as the menu item since they lead to the same screen. Since the button peaks behind the menu, Appium was still picking it up. The solution was simply to change the name of the home button to be different than the menu item for the same screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your element by using **findElementByAccessibilityId** that has **cont-desc**.

```
MobileElement element= driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("\"73: [Office Locations]\"");
element.click();
```

> you can ask your developer to add unique cont-desc in the code.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that the wrong menu item is being selected even when using *findElementByAccessibilityId*. All the other menu items work fine except for this one. For some reason in my test, Leadership is being clicked on instead. In the first screenshot, Appium is not recognizing `73: [Office Locations]` as an *Accessibility Id* as shown by the warning. However, after using Appium Inspector's tap, it suddenly appears as an *Accessibility Id*.

Comment: The element that you want to interact must be visible in the screen. So first step is to show menu item then you will be able to use above code. Also check if "Leadership" menu item has same automation id as "Office Locations"

Comment: They did not have the same locator id. In Android, even when the menu is open, the locators behind it, for, the buttons on the home screen, for example, will still be seen. And one of the home buttons was also "Office Locations" so it's why Inspector was showing a `[2]` index at the end of the xpath. Still not sure why using the same code wasn't working in my test while it was working inside Appium Inspector, but the easy solution was to just change the home button name to something unique.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the element by using xpath and in xpath you need to specify the content description i think this might help

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='description'].click();
```

you have specified in wrong way hence its not clicking the content description showing as it is you have to mentioned it